# OpenGL/3D Acceleration / Working Graphics Driver on Ubuntu 14.04 on MacPro6,1 (Black Cylinder)

Tags: ati

Followed user282366 post and guide : [Mac Pro Cylinder Ubuntu Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacPro)

Had anybody had any luck in getting OpenGL/3D acceleration working and not having a blank screen with the following text _ on top left of screen

I have tried Radeon/FirePro and Catalyst drivers.

Have D500 (3GB) in my MacPro and have monitor attached to both HDMI and Thunderbolt/DisplayPort ports.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no luck here with 3D acceleration, I tried fglrx, fglrx update, radeon and vesa. Only the last one works but you have to specify:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`

in your `/etc/default/grub`